# php json_decode skippes some keys

Tags: php, json

Here is JSON to decode:

```
{"somearray":[
    {
     "id":71398,
     "prices":{
         "SIMPLE":270,
         "VIP":300,
         "SOFA":540,
         "EXTRA":320
         }
    },
    {
     "id":71399,
     "prices":{
         "SIMPLE":190,
         "VIP":190,
         "SOFA":380
         }
     },
    {...}
]}
```

NOTE: that some items have a price "EXTRA", and some DO NOT have it.

JSON is valid according to online JSON validators.
However when you try to decode it in php as

```
json_decode($json, true);
```

(true - is to retrieve data as associative array.)
the key "EXTRA" is ignored by json_decode.

so if you var_dump() the decoded resul
or try $item['prices']['EXTRA']
 there would be no "EXTRA" key-value in it.

WHY???

Comment: Check the data before doing `json_decode` whether EXTRA present or not.

Comment: jsonlint.com says this json is not valid?

Comment: You have a comma after the `'EXTRA':320` section when it is the last value in the prices object

Comment: comma is my typing mistake here at stackoverflow.. corected..

Comment: jslit says it's valid

Comment: What does `$item` represent?

Comment: $item is if you do something like foreach ($parsedJSON['somearray'] as $item) {...}

Answer (score 1):

This works fine when the json is valid:

```
<?php
$json = '{"somearray":[
    {
     "id":71398,
     "prices":{
         "SIMPLE":270,
         "VIP":300,
         "SOFA":540,
         "EXTRA":320'. // There was an extra comma here.
         '}
    },
    {
     "id":71399,
     "prices":{
         "SIMPLE":190,
         "VIP":190,
         "SOFA":380
         }
     }
]}';

print_r(json_decode($json));
?>
```

Output:

```
[somearray] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 71398
                    [prices] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [SIMPLE] => 270
                            [VIP] => 300
                            [SOFA] => 540
                            [EXTRA] => 320
                        )

                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 71399
                    [prices] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [SIMPLE] => 190
                            [VIP] => 190
                            [SOFA] => 380
                        )

                )

        )
```